# quantum capacitance of supercapacitor electrodes, high or low needed?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

quantum capacitance of supercapacitor electrodes should be low or high? to achieve high specific capacitance. The quantum capacitance forms among the layers of low DOS materials when used as an electrode for supercapacitor.

Comment: It got the answer myself. High quantum capacitance is favorable.